# HIVE ALTER SERDE COMMAND

Tags: hive

Is there a command in hive that would alter the serde properties of an existing table . Well the tables are created using `com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde` which needs to be changed to `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde`,I am looking for something like:

`alter table table_X change serde`

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will help:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME SET SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde';
```

Comment: mine required the full class name specification be enclosed in single quotes