# Hive: altering on MetadataTypedColumnsetSerDe in fact results LazySimpleSerDe

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying to alter hive-table in part of setting MetadataTypedColumnsetSerDe.

```
 alter table 'some_table' set serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.MetadataTypedColumnsetSerDe'
```

But as a result I retrieve:

'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'

Comment: This may be version specific issue. its not working for my hive 2.1.1. but some stackoverflow answered this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753104/hive-alter-serde-command. Workaround may be - backup the table, drop it, recreate it using new format, reinsert from backup.

Comment: Thank you. I dropped the table and recreated it with a new SerDe. But with the same result - LazySimpleSerDe instead of MetadataTypedColumnsetSerDe.

Comment: One idea is that MetadataTypedColumnsetSerDe don't exists in classpath. And classloader, without finding it, trying to find SerDe in it parent-context (AbstractSerDe) - then iterate over it childs, find LazySimpleSerDe and load it.